Monitor network usage during a specific time range within the day and generate report on monthly usage when needed
I want to monitor my internet usage via WiFi during a specific time period within the day (ex: from 8AM to 6PM) and get how much data I have used during the current month in a report when needed.
Is there a way to to do this using vnstat or any other program?

The answer to this might be what you're looking for.
man vnstat might also be useful.
If not, you could look into Netdata and Prometheus
